# How to link directly to slides in Supersized 3.2 jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, supersized

Im trying to link directly to a specific slide from a different page. The new features for version 3.2 list that you can “Link directly to slides” but for the life of me I cant figure out how to do this. It doesnt help that Im not much of a programer. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by a different page? Another image or another webpage?

Comment: Docs seem pretty vague: http://www.buildinternet.com/project/supersized/docs.html#slide_links but I guess you'll just access them via `#definedSlideName` hash appended to the URL - these are defined when initializing the `supersized`

Comment: @ Tim - I would like to link to a specific slide from a separate webpage.

Comment: @ m90 - It appears your comment got cut off. Im not sure where to define the names

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
// Executes the function when DOM will be loaded fully
window.onload = myFunction;
 function myFunction(){
      //jQuery.noConflict();

         // Use jQuery via jQuery(...)
         jQuery(document).ready(function($){



    var url = String(window.location); 
    var startslide = 1;
    //AKTUELLES
    if (url.indexOf("aktuelles") != -1)
        {
            startslide = 2;
        }

    if (url.indexOf("fm") != -1)
    {
        startslide = 5;
    }

    if (url.indexOf("produkte") != -1 || url.indexOf("leistungen") != -1)
    {
        startslide = 6; 
    } 

    if (url.indexOf("capitano") != -1 || url.indexOf("eigenreinigung") != -1)
    {
        startslide = 4;
    } 

    if (url.indexOf("service") != -1 || url.indexOf("webcam") != -1)
    {
        startslide = 2;
    } 

    if (url.indexOf("unternehmen") != -1)
    {
        startslide = 2;
    } 

    if (url.indexOf("referenzen") != -1 || url.indexOf("anwenderbericht") != -1)
    {
        startslide = 1;
    } 


    $('#slidercontent').supersized({
        url_local : url,
        start_slide : startslide
    });


});

}

</script>
```

This code i put in the head of the homepage and with the number of the slides you can get the image that you want(put in the whole url or only a special part of it.

With number i mean the sequence of pages in the slide array.

This works perfect for me.